# how to transpose row to columns sequentially with SQL in MS ACCESS database

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, transpose

I'm trying to transpose row to columns sequentially with SQL in MS ACCESS database . I have the SQL below, but it's not right yet:
I want in one query.
If there is an answer then I don't want to use the function in MS Access because I want to use the SQL for VB.Net.
Please Guide Me.

Thanks

```
  TRANSFORM Sum(Tableproduct.[Qty]) AS SumOfQty
SELECT Tableproduct.Codeproduct AS CodeProduct, Tableproduct.Colour AS Colour, Sum(Tableproduct.Qty) AS Total
FROM Tableproduct INNER JOIN SizeProduct ON Tableproduct.Size = SizeProduct.Size
WHERE Tableproduct.Codeproduct = 'A'
GROUP BY Tableproduct.Codeproduct, Tableproduct.Colour
PIVOT SizeProduct.Size;
```

Results from the above SQL code :

| CodeProduct | Colour | Total | L | M | S | XL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Black | 30 |  | 20 |  | 10 |
| A | White | 25 | 10 |  | 15 |  |

I want to add the SQL code below into one query

```
ORDER BY SizeProduct.Sequence ASC
```

Sample Data :

Table TableProduct

| CodeProduct | Colour | Size | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Black | XL | 10 |
| A | White | S | 15 |
| A | Black | M | 20 |
| A | White | L | 10 |

Table Sizeproduct

| Sizeproduct | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| S | 1 |
| M | 2 |
| L | 3 |
| XL | 4 |

Desired Result

| CodeProduct | Colour | S | M | L | XL | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Black |  | 20 |  | 10 | 30 |
| A | White | 15 |  | 10 |  | 25 |

[image: Column Total position]

Answer (score 2):

Specify order of pivot fields with IN() function:

```sql
TRANSFORM 
    Max(Qty)
SELECT 
    CodeProduct,
    Colour,
    Sum(Qty) As Total
FROM 
    Tableproduct
GROUP BY 
    CodeProduct,
    Colour
PIVOT 
    [Size] In ('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL')
```

Use yet another query to force Total field to end:

```sql
Select
    CodeProduct,
    Colour,
    S, M, L, XL,
    Total
From 
    Query1
```

Comment: Sorry I was late in your response, thank you for your answer. This means I have to manually update the list of sizes in the SQL code. Can I directly refer to the table `Sizeproduct` because there are approximately 30 sizes and what do I do if I want to add a total column as desired result?

Comment: Then you must edit the `In` clause before running the query. Or you may be able to implement another technique as described in paragraph _The special case: Multi-Value fields_ in my article [Join (concat) values from one field from a table or query](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33612/Join-concat-values-from-one-field-from-a-table-or-query.html?preview=pFMM6gI5Efc%3D).

Comment: Can I use an inner join to the table `Sizeproduct` ? and 
how can I add a total column in the sql code?

Comment: See edited answer for the Total. Not sure what an inner join should do, though.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the total column position should be after Size. `Not sure what an inner join should do, though.` inner join to table inner join to table `Sizeproduct` to retrieve a column `Sequence` so that it can set the order from size

Comment: For reordering, see extended answer, please. Inner join won't help - SQL cannot be dynamic. So, rewrite the SQL before opening the query.

Comment: for the position for the total column, `Sum(Qty) As Total` can it be after the size .

Comment: @Gustav, Query1 does not have a field Qty. And that second SQL will generate "cannot group on fields selected with *" error. To specify field order in the second SQL, will need to explicitly reference each field. `SELECT CodeProduct, Colour, S, M, L, XL, Total FROM Query1;`.

Comment: @June7 is right. You will have to rewrite the SQL to match the varieties.

Comment: @Gustav , just now I updated the sql code in the post so I want to add sql code  `ORDER BY SizeProduct.Sequence ASC` . Please Guide Me.

Comment: @June7 , just now I updated the sql code in the post so I want to add sql code  `ORDER BY SizeProduct.Sequence ASC` . Please Guide Me. Maybe you can help me

Comment: You can't. The order is alphabetic or determined by the `IN` sequence, and this cannot be set dynamically. So, once again, rewrite the SQL of the query before running it.

Comment: And even if it did work, ASC would not place S first.

Comment: @Gustav , for this `PIVOT [Size] In ('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL')` 
can I use it or `As or Alias` . For example `S` can I use alias?

Comment: No. Must be a value matching the field.

Comment: Also, se my old answer: [Transform/Transpose rows to columns in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69251069/3527297).